# How to convert a numpy matrix to a pandas series?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas

I have the following numpy matrix:

```
array([[64, 22,],
   [58, 64],
   [42, 31])
```

And i want to get the following:

```
pd.DataFrame({'one':"64 22", 'two':"42 31"})
```

My purpose is to convert each row in the numpy.array to a string that
will be used for a pandas dataframe.
Is there some built in pandas function to the rescue?

Comment: What happened to `58, 64`? short answer to your question no as you're wanting to convert the `dtype` to `str` and then concatenate the row values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC you can use [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor and [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) `join`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[64, 22,],   [58, 64],   [42, 31]])
print arr
[[64 22]
 [58 64]
 [42 31]]

li = ['one','two','three']
df = pd.DataFrame(arr, dtype='str', index=li)
print df
        0   1
one    64  22
two    58  64
three  42  31

print df.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x), axis=1)
one      64 22
two      58 64
three    42 31
dtype: object
```

Comment: How can i add a name to the data frame created?

Comment: Do you think names of columns - not `0` and `1` , but `col1` and `col2`? Or name of `Serie` (`print df.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x), axis=1)`)

Comment: I want to give a lable to the row that created.